# Extending this code to open magento subcategories (vertical navigation)

Tags: magento, navigation

Hey guys, I'm wondering if anyone can help me extend this bit of code-

```
<h3>Browse by Category:</h3>

<ul>
<?php
$obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$store_cats = $obj->getStoreCategories();
$current_cat    = $obj->getCurrentCategory();

$current_cat    = (is_object($current_cat) ? $current_cat->getName() : '');

foreach ($store_cats as $cat) {
        if ($cat->getName() == $current_cat) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($cat).'">'.$cat->getName()."</a><ul>";
        foreach ($obj->getCurrentChildCategories() as $subcat) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($subcat).'">'.$subcat->getName()."</a></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul></li>";
    } else {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($cat).'">'.$cat->getName()."</a></li>";
    }
}
?>
</ul>
```

Currently, this opens the subcats on a new page upon clicking(which is good). I have subcats inside subcats, but those never show up.(on the second page)

So This is as far as I'll get-

```
Parent  
-sub  
Parent  
-sub
```

But I need :

```
Parent  
-sub  
---sub  
---sub  
---sub  
-sub  
---sub  
---sub  
---sub
```

Can anyone help? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old Question- I have rebuilt the navigation since then. If anyone needs help feel free to ask.

EDIT -

I found Rico's "Vertical Navigation with CSS Classes" to suit our needs best, with a little modification of the css. It worked right out of the box, and updates depending on the order of our backend categories. He did a great job in allowing the depth of the sub-categories to be opened via the control panel.

The URL can be found here. It's free, and is supported up to 1.5 :

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vertical-navigation-with-css-classes.html

Comment: why don't you share with us? It should be nice to see your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever visit Fishpig website? There is an article related with that topic, maybe you you can try their solution.

[Listing Categories in Magento](http://fishpig.co.uk/category-navigation-listings-in-magento/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this unfortunately accomplishes what I already have. I need the subcat's-sub to display without having to click further.

Comment: @danchet How about this :

    if($this->getSubCategories($c)){
    foreach($this->getSubCategories($c) as $sc){
    foreach($this->getSubCategories($sc) as $ssc){
    ...
    }
    }
    }